# Мальчик увидел на календаре, в красном квадратике, пометку(:) "Школа!"(.)

Tags: пунктуация

Как вы считаете, как следует оформить это предложение:
Мальчик увидел на календаре, в красном квадратике, пометку(:) "Школа!"(.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь две возможности оформления.

Первая — слово в кавычках является членом повествовательного предложения (пометку — какую?); после кавычек ставится точка.
**Мальчик увидел на календаре, в красном квадратике, пометку "Школа!".**

Вторая — цитирование (оформляется как прямая речь); тогда точка после кавычек не ставится.
**Мальчик увидел на календаре, в красном квадратике, пометку: "Школа!"**

*Кстати, на тюбике крема за 300 рублей мы обнаружили пометку «PABA — free»* (из газеты).

*Я справился в магидских хрониках, что это за санаторий, и несколько встревожился, обнаружив пометку «крайне сомнительная эзотерика»* (Д. У. Джонс).

[Как оформлять цитаты?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76)